# Is it possible to build GCC Cross Compiler and Binutils with multiple targets?

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling, binutils

I know how to configure GCC and Binutils for a single target, --target=i686-elf, but I am wondering if is it possible to configure them for multiple targets, i.e both i686-elf and Win32 PE executables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not how that works. You build one set of binutils for each target. The long-form of the names are non-conflicting so you install them all.